vi /etc/ansible/hosts and vi /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg opens an empty file
While I try to run vi etc/ansible/hosts and vi etc/ansible/ansible.cfg opens an empty file and I don't see any by default configurations.
I want that by default configuration file where all commented configurations are present.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#generating-a-sample-ansible-cfg-file

It does not work that way:

no one except you knows what hosts do you want to manage so the inventory must be configured by yourself. Speaking of /etc/ansible/hosts - it's just a default location which does not have to exist. You are expected to define your hosts there if you want to, but there are other options;
same is valid for /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg - but as @β.εηοιτ.βε mentioned, you can generate a sample ansible.cfg file:

You can generate a fully commented-out example ansible.cfg file, for example:
$ ansible-config init --disabled > ansible.cfg

You can also have a more complete file that includes existing plugins:
$ ansible-config init --disabled -t all > ansible.cfg




P.S. Note that you used relative paths instead of absolute ones - most likely it was a typo.
